# Does JBoss AS 5.1.0 support IPv6

Tags: ipv6, jboss5.x

I like to know if JBoss AS 5.1.0 does support IPv6.
According to the [Enterprise documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Administration_And_Configuration_Guide/ch03.html#idp24404384) it does not ([Version 4.3 does with limitation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.3/html/Server_Configuration_Guide/ch02.html#idp6047168)).

Is there an official document of the community server which say yes or no?

Answer (score 0):

I've found this information:
JBoss community [link](https://community.jboss.org/thread/168121?tstart=0&_sscc=t)
Bug [link](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-8540)

So the answer is no.